# Bluebeam licensing in a VMWare Horizon environment

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtual-desktop

We're starting the process to move our users over to a virtual desktop environment using VMWare Horizon client. All the Appvolumes we have set up are working great so far but there is one final roadblock I'm running into. The users want to use Bluebeam PDF on their virtual desktop, but due to the way the Bluebeam licensing works, it won't hold the license key when the users appstack is applied. So every time they reboot or log out they have to resubmit the license information. Obviously this isn't feasible.

Does anyone have any experience with this? The only thing I can think of is adding Bluebeam with a license to the master image and not within an appvol. But I don't know if that will work and i'm almost positive that would put us out of license compliance, even though we already have purchased enough licenses for all our users. Any ideas?

Thanks!